# How to start developing project management tool?

Tags: software-development, product-management, development-process, project-management-style

I have been nominated for developing a project management tool for my organization where all project related information, check list and related information to be stored (as of now, no concrete requirements are listed). With reference to that, how shall I start listing requirements? Basic requirements I've listed are, project information (where scope, objective, title and other related information to be saved), checklist mapping with the entitled project, Task, reports, etc... What are the other requirements which could be part of this project? What approach do I need to follow? Any reference or open source PM tools?

Comment: You want the internet to provide your requirements?! Unfortunately this question is likely to be closed as either "Too Broad" (the requirements are potentially unbounded) or "Opinion Based" (Everyone's point of view is equally valid). Beyond asking for some requirements suggestions there doesn't seem to be an actual question here.

Comment: I humbly submit that if you have to ask this level of question, you may not be the right person for the job? If the project is important to your organization, they should invest in the human capital expertise or source a third party developer. In all likelihood there is probably an off-the-shelf product for Real Estate project management that would fit the bill nicely and avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: After you have your requirements/specification, you should take them to Software Recommendations https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com where it is appropriate to ask the question of what software best meets these specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Requirements flow from desired business capabilities. So first step is to engage your stakeholders/internal customers to figure out what business capabilities they want. For example, is this a tool for PMs to manage schedule and budget better? Or is it intended to support timely reporting to senior management? Is monitoring risk a big thing or a little thing? What about long term benefits realization? And is there an off-the-shelf solution that can deliver the business capabilities that I need?

You also need to consider what requirements exist outside of mere systems, in other words what processes does the tool support and how do the tool and processes relate to your organization. Remember that this is just a tool, if you don't have an effective way to use it or if it isn't aligned with your organization the tool could be worse than useless.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and I must say it is very much informative. I have been asked to submit proposal, like what things shall we include in this tool. (Currently It will be used for real estate project) 

Here I would also like to highlight that, I want to make this tool generalize so that it could be used in any industry by making minimum changes.

Would you please help to figure out what business capabilities could be included?

Comment: Any reference document or link will be appreciated.

Comment: @kartik - I'm not sure if you understood the implications of the answer I gave. You need to identify your stakeholders and talk to them, not a message board, to understand what they value and derive your business capabilities and requirements based on that. Read through http://calleam.com/WTPF/?page_id=2338, doing requirements on your own will result in you meeting the first three causes of failure under stakeholder engagement.

Comment: Yes true. I've already arranged meeting with stakeholders. I will update that soon. I was just saying, is there anything I shall recommend to them?

Comment: Information provides in the given link is informative. Thanks.